# Is there a concise way to create an InputSupplier for an InputStream in Google Guava?

Tags: java, io, guava

There are a few factory methods in Google Guava to create InputSuppliers, e.g. from a `byte[]`:

```
ByteStreams.newInputStreamSupplier(bytes);
```

Or from a `File`:

```
Files.newInputStreamSupplier(file);
```

Is there a similar way to to create an `InputSupplier` for a given `InputStream`?

That is, a way that's more concise than an anonymous class:

```
new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
    public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
        return inputStream;
    }
};
```

Background: I'd like to use InputStreams with e.g. `Files.copy(...)` or `ByteStreams.equal(...)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, I haven't seen anything.
I think you have found the best way.
The only alternative where to store the inputstream in a byte array or a file and create a Supplier with ByteStreams.newInputStreamSupplier() or Files.newInputStreamSupplier(), but I would discourage to do like that.
You could also use

```
public static long copy(InputStream from, OutputStream to)
```

from

```
ByteStreams
```

see:[src](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19553971/9636 should be the correct answer because it explains why you can't do it.

Comment: You're right, but jbyler has proposed the some solution three years later ;)

Comment: That's the solution I linked to.

Answer (score 13):

There's no way to convert an arbitrary `InputStream` into an `InputSupplier<InputStream>`, because an `InputSupplier<InputStream>` is supposed to be an object that can create a fresh, new `InputStream` every time its `getInput()` method is called.  This is only possible when the underlying source of bytes is available for re-use; hence the factory methods that take a `byte[]` or `File` and return an `InputSupplier<InputStream>`.

As Dimitris suggests, `InputSupplier` relates to `InputStream` in the same way that `Iterable` relates to `Iterator`.  The anonymous class you describe is incorrect because it returns the *same* stream every time `getInput()` is called, so subsequent invocations will return an `InputStream` that is already exhausted and closed.

Here is another problem with your anonymous class: part of the motivation for `InputSupplier` is to limit the visibility of the actual `InputStream` so that it can be closed automatically.  If you wrap an externally-visible `InputStream` in an `InputSupplier` and then pass that into a utility method, the utility method may close your `InputStream`.  You might be OK with that but that's not a clean usage pattern that Guava would want to promote.

When I found myself wanting to do the same thing, I realized I was doing it backwards.  Instead of doing this:

```
Files.copy(InputSupplier.of(inputStream), destinationFile);
```

(doesn't exist), I should instead be doing this:

```
ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, Files.newOutputStreamSupplier(destinationFile));
```

Comment: Can this answer be updated so it's more up-to-date? As time of this comment, all the supplier classes are now deprecated.

Comment: Sorry @chakrit, but I no longer use Guava and I'm not familiar with the current metaphors.  If somebody writes up a new version with the new classes, I'd be happy to vote for it though!

Answer (score 2):

That would be as wrong as wrapping an Iterator to an Iterable, I feel there is like zero probability of such a thing going into the library. As elou says, you can use ByteStreams.copy() method, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious reason to do equals() on two streams.

I understand guava authors hesitation to add such a (trivial) method - how common can it be to fully (or partially, but without knowing where the stream was left, so it's as good as unusable thereafter) read two streams just to see if they are the same, without any other processing of the data? Do these bytes come from a non-repeatable-read source, like a network socket? Otherwise, if it is just a file somewhere, or an in-memory byte array, there are other ways that lend themselves to do an equality test.