# Most readable way to write a ZipEntry to File?

Tags: java

Given [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) `zip`, its [ZipEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) `entry` and target [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) `unzippedEntryFile`, what is the most readable way to write `entry` to `unzippedEntryFile`?

I came up with following solution using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and [Apache.Commons.IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```java
InputSupplier<ByteArrayInputStream> entryInputSupplier = ByteStreams.newInputStreamSupplier(IOUtils.toByteArray(zip.getInputStream(entry)));
Files.copy(entryInputSupplier, unzippedEntryFile);
```

However, something tells me it can be made simplier.

Thanks,
Konrad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what's not readable about your code, other than that you have a lot of nested calls. These can be broken out and assigned to local variables, which would make the code longer (but, in my opinion, a bit more readable).

You do seem to be processing the data twice -- once to read it into a byte array and again to copy it to the file. I haven't tested this, but it should work and cut the amount of data movement in half:

```
final InputStream zipStream = zip.getInputStream(entry);
InputSupplier<InputStream> supplier = new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
    InputStream getInput() {
        return zipStream;
    }
};
Files.copy(supplier, unzippedEntryFile);
```

You could, in fact, create your own little class that implements `InputSuppler<InputStream>`. I'm surprised that I couldn't find one in the Guava library. (Apparently, [others have been surprised at this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363408/is-there-a-concise-way-to-create-an-inputsupplier-for-an-inputstream-in-google-g).)

Comment: By "readable" I also meant concise, so I wanted to avoid creating a new anonymous class and generally I believed less calls can be made to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick link that might have all the possible scenarios for [Zip file operation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingtheContentsofaZIPFile.htm). If it is simple file operation, here is the tutorial from Sun. Am sure there are lot of open source API's. Here is the link to [IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html). Cheers